# Using a UIImage from a String file path

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to populate a collection view with thumbnail images from user-recorded videos. Once the video is recorded and chosen, this function saves the video to the documents directory...

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
        // Componenets for a unique ID for the video
        var uniqueVideoID = ""
        var videoURL:NSURL? = NSURL()
        var uniqueID = ""
        uniqueID = NSUUID().uuidString

        // Get the path as URL
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL as NSURL?
        let myVideoVarData = try! Data(contentsOf: videoURL! as URL)

        // Write the video to the Document Directory at myVideoVarData (and set the video's unique ID)
        let docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = docPaths[0] as AnyObject
        uniqueVideoID = uniqueID  + "VIDEO.MOV"
        let docDataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(uniqueVideoID) as String
        try? myVideoVarData.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), options: [])
        print("docDataPath under picker ", docDataPath)
        print("Video saved to documents directory")

        // Create a thumbnail image from the video (first frame)
        let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath))
        let assetImageGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImageGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)
        if let videoImage = try? assetImageGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil) {
            // Add thumbnail to documents directory
            let thumbnailPath = saveImageToDocumentDirectory(UIImage(cgImage: videoImage))
            // Add thumbnail & video path to Post object
            let video = Post(pathToVideo: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), thumbnail: thumbnailPath)
            posts.append(video)
            print("Video saved to Post object")
        }
    }
}
```

... using this function to save the thumbnail image to the directory:

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(_ chosenImage: UIImage) -> String {
    let directoryPath =  NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directoryPath) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: directoryPath), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    let filename = NSDate().string(withDateFormatter: yyyytoss).appending(".jpg")
    let filepath = directoryPath.appending(filename)
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filepath)
    do {
        try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0)?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
        return String.init("/Documents/\(filename)")

    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("file cant not be save at path \(filepath), with error : \(error)");
        return filepath
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that I have a collection view of UIImage cells that I'd like to populate with the saved thumbnails. I have a `Post` object in which the thumbnail is saved as a `String`, as seen above. So when it comes to setting the cell images in the collection view, I'm not sure how to use the thumbnail from my object (a string file path to the UIImage) as the UIImage here:

```
cell.postImage.image = posts[indexPath.row].thumbnail
```

Does anybody know how to make this possible?

EDIT: Update function to save the image and get the file path :

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(_ chosenImage: UIImage) -> URL {
    let fm = FileManager.default

    // Get date/time
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddhhmmss"
    let now = dateFormatter.string(from: NSDate() as Date)

    // Make the filename (String)
    let filename = now.appending(".jpg")
    let docsurl = try? fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,
                             appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    // Make the filepath
    let filepath = docsurl?.appendingPathComponent(filename)

    // Save filename to documents directory
    do {
        try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0)?.write(to: docsurl!, options: .atomic)

    } catch {
        print(error)
        print("file cant not be save at path \(filepath), with error : \(error)");

        // Return the filepath
        return filepath!
    }
}
```

And changed `thumbnail` in `Post` object to be of type URL. Appended the post object like this:

```
let thumbnailPath = saveImageToDocumentDirectory(UIImage(cgImage: videoImage))

let video = Post(pathToVideo: URL(fileURLWithPath: docDataPath), thumbnail: URL(fileURLWithPath: thumbnailPath))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use `NSDate`, `NSData`, `NSURL` etc in Swift 3.
Use only the structs without the `NS` prefix.

Since you have the file path, create the image from the file and assign it to `postImage`

```
let filePath = posts[indexPath.row].thumbnail
cell.postImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:filePath)
```

Note: `NSHomeDirectory().appending("/Documents/")` will not work at all. You have to get the documents directory like in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method.

Comment: The problem is that he _doesn't_ have the file path. He is storing `"/Documents/\(filename)"`, which is totally bogus.

Comment: I know @matt that's why I added the note

Comment: Thanks vadian `UIImage(contentsOfFile...` was what I was trying to figure out. Although as matt says (and you) I'm going to need to re-work how I'm accessing the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're doing with file paths is wrong. Use URLs, obtain them properly, and form them properly. For example:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, 
    appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent(filename)
```

Now save the file to that URL. Also, store the string `filename`. When you later need to retrieve the file at the same URL, start with the stored `filename` and form the URL again by doing exactly the same thing again! Now you can load the UIImage directly using that URL — either fetch the data and call `UIImage(data:)`, or convert the URL to its `path` and call `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to fix this. I was trying to go off of another SO solution and at this point don't know enough about working with directories to fix it on my own so I'll read up and take another look.

Comment: I did my best to update that function, and also changed thumbnail in my object to be a URL. I edited my question to show what I have now, is this more along the lines of what you're suggesting? Let me know if there's anything I can improve. Also I don't fully understand the second part of your answer, on retrieving the URL. Can I not just use `UIImage(contentsOfFile:filePath)`?

Comment: The thing is that you cannot save an entire file path. You must do what I said: save the file _name_, and _reconstruct_ the URL / path any time you want to use it again.

Comment: Ok - So in my saveImage function I should be returning `filename` and not `filepath`, and saving that to my Post object (as a string)? Then in my `cellForItem` I'll be reconstructing the URL then using `cell.postImage.image = UIImage(data: reconstructedPath)`?